# Lotusscript: Not getting the next array index

Tags: lotusscript

I have a button that displays the row  when you select a a column. But I'm having a problem 'coz its not getting the 2nd value on the field. For example, I select the column birthday, but it has two items with the same value(e.g. January 1, 1990), it only displays the row of the first item in the field, not seeing the 2nd item. Can you help me? Here's my code:

```
Sub Getvalue
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim printcolumn As String
Dim columnList() As String
Dim y As Integer

'-- print column --
For a =  0 To 10    
    setfield = "Untitled" &  x
    Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
    printfield = uidoc.FieldGetText(setfield)

    Redim Preserve columnList(11)
    columnList(a) = printfield      
    x = x + 10      
Next    

printcolumn = ws.Prompt(4,"Column List", "Select:", , columnList)       

indexresult = (Arraygetindex(columnList, printcolumn)) + 1

'-- print row --
y = (indexresult*10) + 1

For b =  0 To 9
    setrowfield = "Untitled" &  y
    Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
    printrowfield = uidoc.FieldGetText(setrowfield)

    Redim Preserve rowList(10)
    rowList(b) = printrowfield
    y = y + 1       

Next    
printrow = ws.Prompt (4,"Row List", "", ,rowList)   

'-- for duplicates --
Forall prow In columnList
    If printcolumn = prow Then
        indexresult2 = (Arraygetindex(columnList, prow)) + 1
        z = (indexresult2*10) + 1

        For b =  0 To 9
            setrowfield = "Untitled" &  z
            Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
            printrowfield = uidoc.FieldGetText(setrowfield)

            'Redim Preserve rowList(10)
            rowList(b) = printrowfield
            z = z + 1       
            'printrow = ws.Prompt(4,"Row List", "", ,rowList)                       
        Next    
        printrow = ws.Prompt(4,"Row List", "", ,rowList)    
    End If

End Forall  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `columnList` has to have unique members for `Prompt`. The easiest way to achieve this is to add the row number in front of every line. As a benefit you get selected row number for `indexresult` very easy.

Your list would look like this:

```
1. January 1, 1990
2. January 1, 1990
3. January 1, 1990
...
```

and this is the adapted code:

```
Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Redim Preserve columnList(11)
For a =  0 To 10    
    setfield = "Untitled" &  x
    printfield = uidoc.FieldGetText(setfield)
    columnList(a) = (a+1) & ". " & printfield 
    x = x + 10           
Next    

printcolumn = ws.Prompt(4,"Column List", "Select:", , columnList)       
indexresult = cint(strLeft(printcolumn, "."))
```